# Wireframe and Solid viewports are not showing anything correctly

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

So I have an issue where when I change the viewport to Solid or Wireframe, nothing shows up apart from one small segment of my object as if its being cast towards by the camera.
Below is a screenshot of my model in the workbench renderer where it is all rendering correctly, but when I switch it to solid view the second image is what I see.

[image]

[image]

To me it looks like the camera is projecting some kind of small ray that is only rendering the part of the model that is in that area but I have no idea how to fix it. Wireframe view has the same issue as you can see on the image below.

[image]

Comment: I would like to suggest to consider putting some question into the title instead of a clearly false statement. The viewport works correctly in solid and wireframe modes. You pressed alt+b and defined clipping region. Press alt+b again to remove it.